# How to integrate Dialogflow with Slack using OAuth2

Tags: dialogflow-es, slack-api

I'm trying to get Slack to prompt the user to sign in with their Google account (account link) before they can use my Dialogflow chatbot in Slack. The reason being, is that I need access to their calendar in order to create and modify the events, among other things.

Simply following the Slack integration instructions on the 'Integrations' page in the Dialogflow console didn't work. It immediately installed the app.

Comment: I am not aware of any official support for 3rd party auth. So you would have to implement that yourself. e.g. start Google auth process for every user starting your app the first time

Comment: And you still need the Slack auth so that your app can be installed into a workspace